# Display image from its path stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, json, jquery

I want to display an image from the JSON object and the path of the image stored in MySQL database.

I have **user** table which contains:

- userid
- username
- user_img_path
- user_address

Now, I'm firing a query using PHP like:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `username`,`user_img_path` FROM `users`
```

And I store the output in an array `$rows` and encode this array into JSON as

```
json_encode($rows);
```

and I call this PHP file in my jQuery's `ajax` call and get JSON output. I can display other info properly, but the problem is that I couldn't display the image in HTML using jQuery `ajax`.

```
function  callAjax1()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'userApi.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(rows)
        {
            $.each(rows,function(i,item)
            {
                var user_id=rows[i].user_id;
                var user_name=rows[i].user_name;
                var user_img_path=rows[i].user_img_path;
                console.log(user_id,user_name,user_img_path);
                $("#poll_left_body").append('<a href="#">  <img     src=\https://url/"'+user_img_path+'<label id="user_name" rel="tooltip" title=" Edward  11,356" style="color:black;">'+user_name+'</label></a><a href="/twitter/bootstrap/network" class="social-count">11,356</a>');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please include the display code. Could you give an example of what the image path looks like?

Comment: What do your image paths look like? Have you tried taking a look at your DOM after your AJAX call finished? What did your JS insert in order to show the image?

Comment: have you wrapped your image path inside img tag.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put user_img_path into variable  and use javascript

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = user_img_path;  
var body = document.body;  // use element where you want to display image
body.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are not able to set the path for image.
you can do following:

1) Make sure path you are getting from database is correct and try to hard code it and check image displays or not.

2) in case your path is right, you need to check what json output you are getting ? is it the same which is stored in database? 
to check you can use firebug(console tab)

3) if above steps are correct last and important is to check HTML render by your code. if the code is also correct . then you must be able to see image (if there is no further problem)

Hope it helps.